# How to draw pin grid array in cadsoft Eagle pcb?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I'd like to use a processor that uses a pin grid array. Basically, I'd like to make the prototyping PCB board for it. I'm new to eagle so I made an attempt to do this, and this how it looks like.
[image]

Q1) Do I need to add hole when I make a Via or is the hole also included?

Q2) How can I connect the inner PGA pins to the header pins on the edge (without shorting the lines)?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A1) Pads and vias include holes.  You should be able to see all of the via and pad holes holes if you turn on the 'drills' layer.  The holes layer is for non-plated mounting holes while the drills layer is for plated through via and pad holes.

A2) So long as your outer pinout is sensible, you should be able to do most of this on one layer.  With a standard 5 mil trace/space process, you should have no problem fitting a trace between two pads.  It should be possible to route that whole thing on one layer.

Comment: Note: *Through-hole* pads include holes. SMT pads do not.

Comment: True, but the point is that you should never have to draw holes for individual pins; they should be added automatically along with a pad or via.  The only time you should be drawing holes manually is for mechanical reasons - mounting, airflow, isolation, etc.

Comment: I do agree, but it still seems over-general to say "pads" include holes.